# Storing images in datatable

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to store images in `datatble`  from folder something like below code,I tried this code ,but its not working where I am making mistake

```
private void ViewR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string path = str + "\\images\\";

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();                       
    dt1.Columns.Add("Images", System.Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Bitmap[]"));

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
    {
         string[] allImg = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
         foreach (string imgName in allImg)
         {
             Image img = new Bitmap(imgName);
             //row = dt1.NewRow();
             dt1.Rows.Add(img.GetThumbnailImage(350, 350, null, new IntPtr()));
                            img.Dispose();
         }
    }
    ds.Tables[1].Merge(dt1);
}
```

Comment: Any exception or error message?

Comment: No symply control is not going ahead this line `dt1.Columns.Add("Images", System.Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Bitmap[]"));
`  I am doubtful what type it should be `"System.Drawing.Bitmap[]"` or some other I am not getting it

Comment: I suppose it should be `dt1.Columns.Add("Images", typeof(Bitmap[]));` and check whether directory and files exist

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i checked directory exist der

Comment: Try this dt1.Columns.Add("Images", typeof(Bitmap));

Comment: @SriramSakthivel what abou this line `dt1.Rows.Add(img.GetThumbnailImage(350, 350, null, new IntPtr()));`

Comment: `img.GetThumbnailImage(350, 350, () => false, new IntPtr());` You should pass a delegate in 3rd parameter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38230/discussion-between-durga-and-sriram-sakthivel)